# c# Window Form How Select mysql Data In Textbox1?

Tags: c#, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am fully new in the programming section so don't try bad help pls. 
Actually I am fail focus data from phpmyadmin to c# windows form textbox1.Text area.

My database name: business, Table Name: life, columns Name : Email_id

I need to show email id 10 number row in my textbox1.Text area.

See my code

```
       string connString = "datasource=x5x.1x1.13x.xxx;Database=business;username=sumon;password=root";
       MySqlConnection connect = new MySqlConnection(connString);
       MySqlCommand myCommand = connect.CreateCommand();

       string input = textBox1.Text;

       myCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM life WHERE id = @input";
       connect.Open();

       MySqlDataReader reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

       if (reader.Read())
           textBox1.Text = reader["*"].ToString();

       connect.Close();
```

Comment: What's your problem?

Answer (score 0):

you've missed to set the value for @input. I edited you code (without testing). Give it a try.

```
   string connString = "datasource=x5x.1x1.13x.xxx;Database=business;username=sumon;password=root";
   MySqlConnection connect = new MySqlConnection(connString);
   MySqlCommand myCommand = connect.CreateCommand();

   myCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("input", 10));

   //string input = textBox1.Text;

   myCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM life WHERE id = @input";
   connect.Open();
       MySqlDataReader reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

       if (reader.Read())
           textBox1.Text = reader["Email_id"].ToString();

       connect.Close();
```